# ES6 Import multiple files and extend main object

Tags: ecmascript-6

i would like to extend `A` in `main.js` using multiple import files, example

```
// main.js
A = {
    a : 0
};

import './b.js'
import './c.js'
...

export default A;
```

```
// b.js
import A from './main.js'

A.b = 1;
```

```
// c.js
import A from './main.js'

A.c = 2;
```

```
// App.js
import A from './main.js'

console.log(A);
```

what i get in `console.log(A)` is `{ a : 0 }`

how to extend `A` in `main.js` and while import to `App.js`, `A` will be extended to

```
A = {
    a : 0,
    b : 1,
    c : 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a module, module.exports automatically is initialized to an empty object {}. So when you do something like module.exports = A, what you're doing is to replace this default object with your object A.

What is happening in your code, is that you're defining A but you're not exporting it yet, so what b.js and c.js receives from the import of main.js is not A, but the default module.exports object, and is the one that they are modifying.

So you have 2 options to modify main.js so it works. The first one is to export A before main.js is imported by other modules:

```
// main.js
A = {};

export default A;

import './b.js'
import './c.js'
...
```

The other option, is to not have A at all and work directly with the default object returned by module.exports

```
// main.js
import './b.js'
import './c.js'
...
```